# MySQL queries - defining compound and single indexes across multiple queries. How to prevent the indexes from conflicting and creating slow queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am struggling to work out which columns are best to put my indexes on, when it seems adding additional indexes can have a detrimental effect on the query performance.

For example, I have the following query on a table with around 5m rows;

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = 'a' AND col2 = 'b' AND col3 = 'c';
```

Running this with no indexes takes 12 seconds!

I add a compound index on all 3 columns - `table_col1_col2_col3_index`;

My query now drops down to 2 seconds - great!

I now have another query on the same table (with no indexes on any column):

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = 'a';
```

Running this on its own and the query takes 4 seconds - still pretty slow!

So now I add a single column index to col1 `table_col1_index`

My query reduces down to 0.2 seconds. This is great, however I now run the original query again and notice that it is using this index opposed to the one I specified earlier. The original query is now back up at 6 seconds.

I am unsure how to go about ensuring that both queries can be optimised at the same time.

Comment: What if you just have that original mulit-column index? MySQL should still use that index as long as you are searching for the columns in order. So, if you have a multi-column index set with `col1`, `col2` and `col3` and do a query on `col1` alone, it will still use that index. Or, if you search on `col1` and `col2` - but not if you search on `col2` by itself.

Comment: You imply at some point removing the first compound index; just to be sure, you added it back, right? MySQL is usually pretty good at picking the best index, but when it doesn't there are means to hint or force use of specific indexes. [official ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html)

Comment: Your second query should use the first index, with comparable performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create indexes taking care to leave the most used or selective column on the left and then organizing the indexes if you can so you can use the same index in more queries ..

Furthermore you can always print the index you think is best adapted using FORCE (or IGNORE) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 FORCE INDEX (col3_index)
> WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

- Turn off the query cache, or use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` when doing timing.
- Run each timing test twice.  The first *may* spend extra time fetching data and/or index blocks from disk.  The second timing is better for comparisons.  (And is closer to the way it would be in a "production" server.)
- How many rows are being returned?  That could have an impact.  The 2nd query may be returning many times as many rows.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there could be subtle issues.  (datatypes, column sizes, collations, who-knows-what)
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- As written, each of your examples should say "Using index", meaning that the index "covers" the query, which means that *all* the columns in the `SELECT` exist in the `INDEX` being used.
- Do not use "index hints" -- while it may help a query today, it may hurt it more tomorrow.
- All of your examples would ('should') benefit from `INDEX(col1, col2, col3)`, in *that order*; I would not add any others.